# Can i have Test execution (Robot FR) statistics as custom statistics chart in teamcity statistics Tab?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, robotframework

i'm trying to display test results statistics in the statistics tab in Teamcity, so i will be able to see if a test is always failed (for example) via the static chart.

- I'm not trying to have dashboard of the last tests executed ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058044/can-i-get-statistics-for-test-cases-steps-inside-robot-framework/46058510)) can't help me.
- I can't use Robot Framework listeners because i use scheduletask on the remote machine to run test cases.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by _"I can't use Robot Framework listeners because i use scheduletask"_? What does the use of scheduletask have to do with being able to use listeners?

Comment: TeamCity agent will register a scheduletask with tests suites that will be executed on the remote machine.
il i use Robot Framework listeners it will just display messages in the build log, what i want is to have a statistics chart in teamcity statistics Tab with all tests results statistics not only the last.

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question. Something must eventually execute a script -- either robot or some other script that calls robot. Have it call a script that calls robot with the `--listener` argument.

Comment: I already used listeners but, ... but it don't allows me to do what i want to do. 
What i want to do is to use this : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Custom+Statistics 
to create a custom chart and to tests results (number of tests failed/succeeded), and to display it in the new chart. 
But technically i don't know how to do it.

Comment: So, you're asking how to create a custom chart? Shouldn't you be using the teamcity documentation for that?

Comment: @BryanOakley, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by using the : "Providing data using the teamcity-info.xml file" [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)
after creating the "teamcity-info.xml" file in the root of the build, i create a custom chart with the keys : chart1Key / chart2Key (existing in the "teamcity-info.xml" file). So i will be able to see the OK/KO tests percents. 
[Find here the Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQcYH.png)